# Additional badges for hitting the voting cap?

Tags: discussion, badge-request

I know that there is already a badge for hitting the voting cap for a single day (Suffrage), but could we add in a few new badges for hitting the cap for multiple days, much like the reputation cap? Thanks.

Note, this is NOT for hitting the reputation cap. I already know that badges exist for hitting the reputation cap, but there's nothing for hitting the vote cap more than once, so far as I can tell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy to cast all your votes in a day. It would be too easy to game badges like this by indiscriminate upvoting. Admittedly, the existing [Suffrage badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/804/suffrage) could be easily gamed, but it really serves as a way to get *new* users interested and familiar with voting, since it's a key part of what makes this community work.

Besides, there are actually quite a few badges earned for voting already:

- [Supporter](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/6/supporter)
- [Critic](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/7/critic)
- [Suffrage](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/804/suffrage)
- [Civic Duty](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/32/civic-duty)
- [Electorate](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/155/electorate)
- [Sportsmanship](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/805/sportsmanship)

Comment: Red Unicorn approves.

Answer (score 1):

I think *too many* badges for hitting the rep cap encourages indiscriminate voting. And we've already got Civic Duty and Electorate.

I'd rather see a few more targeted badges to encourage voting. Perhaps something for voting on 10/50/150 questions with tags which you have a high score in, for example. Not your own, of course.

That'd encourage people to vote in their areas of expertise.

Comment: Sounds kind of like [Sportsmanship](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/805/sportsmanship). ;)

Comment: @gnostradamus — yes, but more broad. Plus, with Sportsmanship, you might provide terrible answers and then vote up the good ones.

Comment: Providing terrible answers will get you downvoted, so people aren't likely to do that

Comment: You need to earn [at least one upvote for your answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions), so terrible probably won't cut it.

Comment: Well, mediocre answers, then. That's pretty easy to do. I didn't necessarily mean as a malicious/gaming-the-system tactic. Sportsmanship is kind of a "while I'm at it, vote up the other answers" badge.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an alternative to this would be a "GroupThink" badge (name taken from @mattdm), given to the first person to vote on an answer or question that received XX votes, where XX is something around 10-25?